# Is this really Cause of using FTP code of java?

Tags: java

I got the data from the mainframe application. That file is the name of 'sample.txt' file. When i read the data using the java code through the 'FTP' to store it the data to oracle database. It shows some special characters in the name field. Additionly one information our product we are using the internationalization also . We use the portuguese, spanish,english. I run this using the standalone java program.

For Example the given input,

```
DTALRVAQCRAÜL TORRENTS  +34 93 8640317  +34 93 8640304   RAUL.TORRENS@TRW.COM 20100511FAO
DTALRVAQCRAÜL TORRENTS  +34 93 8640317  +34 93 8640304   RAUL.TORRENS@TRW.COM 20100511FAO
```

output is ,

```
DTALRVAQCRAðL TORRENTS  +34 93 8640317  +34 93 8640304   RAUL.TORRENS@TRW.COM 20100511FAO
DTALRVAQCRAðL TORRENTS  +34 93 8640317  +34 93 8640304   RAUL.TORRENS@TRW.COM 20100511FAO
```

What is the solution for me to overcome this issue.

My sample java file is ,

```
public void loadData() throws Exception {

          emailMsg.setLength(0);           
          BufferedReader br = null;       
          int r12InsCnt = 0; 
          int r12UpdCnt = 0;
          String strLine = null;          
          int totalrows = 0; int trailerCnt = 0;
          String rundate = "";
          String endDate = "";
          Connection conn = null;        
          CallableStatement cs = null;
          String tmpFilename="";
          List regns = new ArrayList();
          BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
          int buffer = 0;
          InputStream in;
          FileInputStream fstream1=null;
          File tempFile = null;

          String METHOD_NAME = "loadData";            
          try
          {                           
              String DATE_FORMAT = "MMddyyyy";
              java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
              Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
              String today = sdf.format(c1.getTime()); //mmddyyyy

              CommonUtil cu = new CommonUtil();
              rundate = cu.getCurrentDtTimestamp("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.S");            

              //get NAS server details from DynoProp table
              PropertyManager propmanager = PropertyManager.getInstance();            
              PropertyGroup vrpgProGroup = propmanager.getGroup("ServerCredentials");       
              String user = vrpgProGroup.getString("id");             
              String password = vrpgProGroup.getString("password"); 
              String serverName = vrpgProGroup.getString("server");

              FtpClientAttributes ftpAttribs = new FtpClientAttributes.Builder(serverName,user,password).build();
              FtpProxyClient ftp = new FtpProxyClient(ftpAttribs);                  
              //ftp.setBinaryMode();
              ftp.setAsciiMode();
              ftp.changeDirectory("Vrpg");

              if(ftp.isFileExists("vrpg.contacts.txt"))
              {
                     tmpFilename = "vrpg_contacts_Pr_" + today + ".txt";
                     ftp.renameFile("vrpg.contacts.txt", tmpFilename);
                     in = ftp.getFile(tmpFilename);

                     //String tempDir = "/proj/mingle/was/install/mingle_mingleEAR.ear/mingleWeb.war/vrpg/";
                     String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/";                    

                     if("DESKTOP".equalsIgnoreCase(System.getProperty("DEPLOYED_ENVIRONMENT"))) {
                         tempDir = "C:/SDPRNG/vrpg/"; 
                     }

                     bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempDir + tmpFilename));                                        
                      while ((buffer = in.read()) != -1) {
                          bos.write(buffer);
                      }
                      bos.flush();
                      bos.close();                    
                      ftp.cleanup();

                      tempFile = new File(tempDir + tmpFilename);
                      fstream1 = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
                      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream1,"CP1252"));

                      conn = DBConnection.getmingleConnection();
                      PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

                        try{
                            if(conn!=null){
                            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(mingleQuery.UPDATER12DELETEFLAG);
                            pstmt.execute();
                            }
                        }catch(SQLException e){
                            throw new mingleBusinessException(
                                    new ruralExceptionAttributes.Builder(
                                    CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME).build(),
                                    "Getting exception while updating the delete flag in loadData ", e);
                        }

                      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)                       
                      { 
                          try
                          {
                               //Header:"AA", Trailer:"ZZ", Detail:"DT" record.
                               if(strLine.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("ZZ"))
                               { trailerCnt = Integer.parseInt(strLine.substring(36,43)); }

                               if(strLine.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("DT"))
                               {                  
                                  totalrows++;
                                  System.out.println("The Values is :"+strLine.length());
                                  //System.out.println("calling SP for:" + strLine.substring(2,7));
                                  //insert to R12
                                   try
                                   {                   
                                     cs = null;
                                     cs = conn.prepareCall("{call createDetailContactRawdata(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");                      
                                     cs.setString(1, strLine.substring(2,7).trim());  //sitecode
                                     cs.setString(2, "vrpg");
                                     cs.setString(3, strLine.substring(7,9).trim()); //title                     
                                     cs.setString(4, strLine.substring(160).trim()); //org
                                     cs.setString(5, strLine.substring(9,41).trim()); //name
                                     cs.setString(6, strLine.substring(41,63).trim()); //phone
                                     cs.setString(7, strLine.substring(63,85).trim()); //cell
                                     cs.setString(8, strLine.substring(85,107).trim()); //fax
                                     cs.setString(9, strLine.substring(107,152).trim()); //email
                                     cs.setString(10, strLine.substring(152,160));      //last update date                  
                                     cs.registerOutParameter(11, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                                     cs.registerOutParameter(12, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
                                     cs.execute();                          
                                     if(!"S".equals(cs.getString(11))){
                                        emailMsg.append(cs.getString(11));                                          
                                     } 
                                     else 
                                     { 
                                        if(cs.getString(12).equalsIgnoreCase("I")) r12InsCnt++;
                                        if(cs.getString(12).equalsIgnoreCase("U")) r12UpdCnt++;
                                     }
                                     cs.close();                                                    
                                   } catch(Exception e) {
                                     System.out.println("sp error:" + e.getMessage());  
                                     emailMsg.append("Error occured executing SP:" + strLine.substring(2,7)+strLine.substring(7,9).trim()+ strLine.substring(160).trim()+ e.getMessage() + "\n");
                                   }
                               }//end if DT

                          }catch(Exception e){
                             System.out.println("error inside while" + e.getMessage()); 
                             emailMsg.append("Error reading vrpg contacts file:" +  strLine.substring(0,25)+ e.getMessage()+ "\n");
                             log.logp(Level.INFO,CLASS_NAME,"loadData", "error reading vrpg contacts file" + e.getMessage().toString()); 
                          }

                      } //end while

                      try{
                            if(conn!=null){
                            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(mingleQuery.DELETER12_DELETEFLAG_Y);
                            pstmt.execute();
                            }
                        }catch(SQLException e){
                            throw new mingleBusinessException(
                                    new ruralExceptionAttributes.Builder(
                                    CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME).build(),
                                    "Getting exception while deleting the records with delete flag 'Y' in loadData ", e);
                        }

                      br.close();
                      conn.close();
                      if(pstmt != null) pstmt.close();

                      //System.out.println("Total Rows ** :" + totalrows); 
                      //System.out.println("Trailer Count** :" + trailerCnt); 

                      if(totalrows < trailerCnt) { emailMsg.append("Total rows processed is less than trailer record count:" + totalrows + "/" + trailerCnt + "\n"); }

                     /*System.out.println("r12InsCnt:" + r12InsCnt);                 
                      System.out.println("r12UpdCnt:" + r12UpdCnt);*/

                     endDate = cu.getCurrentDtTimestamp("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                     //create log for batch process with number of rows retrieved from vrpg and rows inserted into mingle
                     BatchLogBO batchLogBO = new BatchLogBO();
                     batchLogBO.setBusnType(busnType);          
                     batchLogBO.setRatingRegion(region);            
                     batchLogBO.setStartDate(rundate);
                     batchLogBO.setEndDate(endDate);
                     batchLogBO.setRowsReceived(totalrows);
                     batchLogBO.setRowsInserted(r12InsCnt);
                     batchLogBO.setRowsUpdated(r12UpdCnt);
                     batchLogBO.setRowsDeleted(0);
                     batchLogBO.setBatchName("vrpgCONATCTS");
                     batchLogBO.setBatchType("DAILY");
                     batchLogBO.setvrpgCode("NONE");
                     batchLogBO.setLastUpdtPgmCode("BATCH");
                     try
                     { 
                          mingle_BINDING_AS.beginTransaction();
                          batchLogBO = mingle_BINDING_AS.bindCreateOrUpdate(batchLogBO);
                          mingle_BINDING_AS.commitTransaction();
                     } catch(Exception e) {
                          emailMsg.append("Error inserting batchLog:" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
                     }                                      
                     //System.out.println("about to run load instance for all regions");
                     try
                     {
                         //call loadInstance method to load instance data for each region                    
                         regns = getRegions();
                         for(int k=0; k<regns.size(); k++) {                         
                           loadInstance(cu.getCurrentDtTimestamp("MM/dd/yyyy"),regns.get(k).toString());
                         }
                     }catch(Exception e) {
                        emailMsg.append("Error getting regions to run loadInstance:" + e.getMessage() + "\n"); 
                     }

                 } else {                  
                   Mailbox.sendMail("rpgsupp@rural.com", "rpgsupp@rural.com", System.getProperty("DEPLOYED_ENVIRONMENT"), "vrpg Contacts file not found on NAS");
                   return;
                 }

                 if ( (emailMsg.toString().length() > 1) && (!emailMsg.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(null)) && (!emailMsg.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) ) {     
                     Mailbox.sendMail("rpgsupp@rural.com", "rpgsupp@rural.com", System.getProperty("DEPLOYED_ENVIRONMENT")+ ":Load vrpg Contacts Details",  emailMsg.toString());
                 }

                 tempFile.delete(); //delete tmp file from app server

                 ftp = new FtpProxyClient(ftpAttribs);
                 emailMsg.append(cu.deletefile(ftp,today,"vrpg_Contacts_")); //delete old files from NAS
                 ftp.cleanup();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("inside final exception:" + e.getMessage());
                if(br != null) br.close();              
                if(conn !=null) conn.close();
                emailMsg.append("Error:" + e.getMessage()+ "\n");
                Mailbox.sendMail("rpgsupp@rural.com", "rpgsupp@rural.com", System.getProperty("DEPLOYED_ENVIRONMENT")+ ":Load vrpg Contacts Details",  emailMsg.toString());
                log.logp(Level.INFO,CLASS_NAME,"loadData", "error getting vrpg contacts file from NAS:" + e.getMessage().toString());
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem, most likely:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream1,"CP1252"));
```

You're converting the bytes of the file into characters by assuming that they're using the CP1252 encoding.

If the actual encoding of the file is *not* CP1252, then the bytes will map into the wrong characters.  (Just about every encoding uses the same values for "ASCII characters", so you'd only see the error on "special" characters.)  What made you decide to use CP1252 for decoding, and are you sure this is correct?

To resolve your problem, find out the actual encoding used by these files, and pass that into the InputStreamReader constructor instead.

Comment: how can i recover the problem.

Comment: **Addition:** Moreover, if the text file actually IS in CP1252, then it won't be able to contain characters from different languages. It would be the best to switch to UTF-8 in this case.

Comment: @KallarMannargudi Find out the actual encoding of your text file. When you do - specify it in that line of code.

Comment: i read the *.txt file using the java code to store it in to the database. then it shows the data in the product UI of our application contains some special characters. For example It changes the character from ‘U’ to ‘Ü’ and sometimes ‘a’ to ‘ä’.

Comment: @Max thanks for spelling it out; I thought the solution was implied from the description, but I've edited it into my post regardless.

Comment: hi max, i used the UTF-8 instead of CP1252. it doesn't works.

Comment: @Kallar I don't think you've quite understood what people are trying to say here.  **Step one** - find out what the encoding is of the files on the FTP site.  This is very important and cannot be skipped.  **Step two** - use *that* encoding in the constructor of your `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: hi max. really i can't understand. please explain me using the above program. thanks. what i changed is                          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream1,"UTF-8")); but am getting the same output. The data comes from a to  ‘a’ to ‘ä’.

Comment: @Kallar Did you read my previous comment and do step one?  No-one can help you any more until you've done that.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle - The text file also contains the special characters before i fed into the "FTP" process. Because in our application we used three languages where as english,Portuguese,Spanish. If the user type the name as portuguese it would change the special characters. So then the mainframe take the datas and write into the text file.

Comment: @Kallar: What. Is. The. File. Encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when communicating with the Mainframe.  It depends how you FTP the file across, in that it may automatically be converted to ASCII in the transfer.

Typically, binary transfers will give you Native EBCDIC and you need to convert it to ASCII.  If your file contains binary numerics (Such as COMP3), you may not want to convert the data in the stream.

The US EBCDIC  code page is typically Cp1047, here's a code sample to convert the string to ASCII.  You can pass whatever codepage text ("Cp1047" for US) to the routine for your file:

```
    // Convert Binary EBCDIC Data to String
public static String toASCII(byte[] arr, int offset, int len, String codepage){
    try {
        return new String(arr, offset, len, codepage);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Occurred translating EBCDIC data to String");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what codepage your FTP server is using to convert the file?

Comment: i read the *.txt file using the *.java file to store it in to the oracle DB

Comment: i read the *.txt file using the java code to store it in to the database. then it shows the data in the product UI of our application contains some special characters. For example It changes the character from ‘U’ to ‘Ü’ and sometimes ‘a’ to ‘ä’.

Comment: is this any possible to change the 'Ü’ to 'U'